# Bringing back default ubuntu shell option in login

Tags: 14.04, gnome, auto-login

I use Ubuntu 14.04 with GNOME 3.10

Some time ago i set my default login shell to be GNOME and i can't choose anything else but GNOME now.

Simply when i have the choice to login as me or guest, when i click on my profile, I get logged in.

There is no way to choose with what shell I want to log in.

I don't remember where did I set the default login shell to be GNOME.

How can I undo this change? I want to be able to login with standard ubuntu 14.04 shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your Desktop environment at your screen login menu.
If it isn't appearing there , install gnome classic from software center.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case your login manager is not LightDM, you can set it using -

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Select LightDM if prompted.

Then, use the method provided by @yask to choose the desktop environment.